# How to detect ellipsis in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, detection

I'm programming on `Objective C`. I have a `UITableView` with `UILabel`'s. How to detect ellipsis in a `UILabel`?

Comment: what do you mean by 3 dots? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: are you want to check 3dots which is like a.bd.jdkjd.  or abd...hdh?

Comment: 3 dots means ellipsis or three dots any where in string?

Comment: 3 dots means ellipsis

Comment: Are you wanting to find an actual ellipsis in the text, or do you want to know if the text in the label was automatically truncated and is therefore showing an elipsis that isn't actually in the text?

Comment: I want to know if the text in the label was automatically truncated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we can get width of the text which will be rendered in label. Then we can compare that width against the width of the label. If that width exceeds then string is truncated otherwise not.

**UPDATE**

If label is having lines then count number of lines and check against lablewidth*numofLines

```
UILabel *lblAppTitle = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:777];    
CGSize stringSize = [lblAppTitle.text sizeWithFont:lblAppTitle.font];

//Count Number of lines
[lblAppTitle sizeToFit];
int numLines = (int)(lblAppTitle.frame.size.height/lblAppTitle.font.leading);

if (stringSize.width > (lblAppTitle.frame.size.width)*numLines)
    NSLog(@"truncated string");
else
    NSLog(@"did not truncate string");
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: +1 I didn't see your answer before posting mine. This is the right approach.

Comment: +1 this answer will work. Not my one :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This method doesn't correctly work. All labels which have line count >= 2 are truncated. But label which has 2 line may be not truncated

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: Plz help sveta, I am new in ios, you can surely help her. Even Bhargavi will be seeing this.

Comment: @Sveta just look on the update and try that. let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Sveta you are welcome always :)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *str = @"Hello this is the ...";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"..."];
if (range.location>0 && range.length == 3) {
    //Found
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 UILabel *lbl ;
 lbl.text = @"Hello..World.";
 NSString * charToCount = @".";
 NSArray * array = [lbl.text componentsSeparatedByString:charToCount];
 if([array count] >= 3)
    NSLog(@"Found");
 else 
    NSLog(@"Not Found");
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.